# data haul -- meaning?

Tags: meaning

Source: http://news.yahoo.com/probe-heads-towards-historic-comet-landing-092723386.html

> It has enough battery power to provide about 60 hours of work, but can continue until March with a solar recharge.
>   It accounts for about a fifth of the mission's total expected **data haul** from the marathon mission.

How do you understand this phrase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is using [haul](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/haul) according to the second definition in the link.

> haul(n.): a usually large amount of something that has been stolen, collected, or won

The mission is collecting a large amount of information, about 1/5 of which will come from Philae.